# How to check if I am connected to a certain wifi network?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, internet-connection

I am completely new to developing android apps. I want to have my app (constantly or maybe every few minutes) check in the background whether I am connected to a certain wifi network. If so, it should call a certain class. Unfortunately, there is not much of a code snippet I could provide as of now. Can any one help me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a method that will determine if the device is currently connected to a specific SSID:

```
public boolean isConnectedTo(String ssid, Context context) {
    boolean retVal = false;
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null) {
        String currentConnectedSSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        if (currentConnectedSSID != null && ssid.equals(currentConnectedSSID)) {
            retVal = true;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Then just use the method like this:

```
if (isConnectedTo("SOME_SSID", MainActivity.this)) {
    //Call into other class
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this looks very nice. The only thing now is when I execute the if statement I get an error message saying "invalid method declaration, return type required". Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: @Philipp Are you sure that the method declaration is exactly as it is in the answer?  `public boolean isConnectedTo(String ssid, Context context) {`

Comment: This works if the location permission has been granted to the App. Otherwise, <ssid unknown> is returned. Notice this function got deprecated in API 31.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

`android.net.wifi.WifiInfo.getSSID()`

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID()) for this method. There also is more useful info you can get from `WifiInfo`.